# Convert anonymous acccount to Phone Number Account

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Looking at the [Firebase Authentication documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/anonymous-auth#convert-an-anonymous-account-to-a-permanent-account) it *looks like* one could only link an anonymous account to **either** email, Google or Facebook, but there is no specific statement regarding this question.

Because I was unable to find any clear method in the API that would allow to convert to a phone number account, I was wondering whether or not there is any possibility to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also connect an anonymous account with an account for phone number authentication. Similar to all the example on the [documentation you linked](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/anonymous-auth#convert-an-anonymous-account-to-a-permanent-account), you'll use the `credential(withVerificationID: verificationCode:)` method of the provider. So something like:

```
guard let authentication = user.authentication else { return }
let credential = PhoneAuthProvider.credential(withVerificationID: authentication.idToken,
                                              verificationCode: verificationCode)
```