# How do I link an Anonymous Account to a Phone Number in Flutter?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, flutter

This is generally a possibility in Firebase Authentication as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52578795/6509751).
However, for Flutter there are only three premade linking methods, i.e. **`linkWithEmailAndPassword`**, **`linkWithGoogleCredential`** and **`linkWithFacebookCredential`**.

I already found out that there is no straight forward implementation for this [in Flutter](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/22491).
I am wondering if there is any way to currently achieve this.

Comment: Given what I answered on [your question yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52578119/convert-anonymous-acccount-to-phone-number-account), what did you try? You'll find that you get much more response to a "here's what I'm trying to do, here's what I tried" than on a "here's what I'm trying to do, how do I do it?" or "here's what I'm trying to do, is it possible?"

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen The problem with plugins in Flutter is that all the methods are handled through Platform channels, which means that there is not logic written in Dart code for this plugin, but it will only call Android and iOS methods that the plugin provides. There are some for phone authentication, but they will just register a new Firebase User and not link it together. I thought that someone might know if there was an entry point. If not, this is an issue of the plugin and one would either have to wait or write the platform code in Android and iOS seperately themselves.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Looking at it though, I will just make a pull request on GitHub to allow this with the help of what you have answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
```

You can send a verficication SMS using [`verifyPhoneNumber`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseAuth/verifyPhoneNumber.html) and retrieve the `verificationID` needed to create a `PhoneAuthCredential` from the `codeSent` callback:

```
firebaseAuth.verifyPhoneNumber(phoneNumber: ..., codeSent: (verificationId, [_]) async {
    // you need to get the SMS code from the user before the next step, e.g. by using a TextField
    // in this example that would be stored in [codeRetrieved]
    (await firebaseAuth.currentUser()).linkWithCredential(
        PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verificationId: verificationId, smsCode: codeRetrieved)
    );
  });
```

If the user gets verified automatically on Android, you can make use of `verificationCompleted`, which gives you a pre configured credential:

```
firebaseAuth.verifyPhoneNumber(..., verificationCompleted: (credential) async {
          (await firebaseAuth.currentUser()).linkWithCredential(credential);
        });
```

Comment: This won't work if Android automatically verified the user. Before we can call the PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential, the SDK automatically creates a new user.